# How will I fix this table using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL. I am using MySQL 8.0.

My schema and sample data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE AA (
    A int
);

insert into AA (A) values (1);
insert into AA (A) values (1);
insert into AA (A) values (2);
insert into AA (A) values (2);
insert into AA (A) values (1);
insert into AA (A) values (3);

CREATE TABLE BB (
    code int,
    description varchar(30)
);

insert into BB (code, description) values (1, 'Male');
insert into BB (code, description) values (2, 'Female');
```

Here's my code

```
with totalcount as (
    select code as 'CODE',
        description as 'SEX',
        count(A) AS 'TOTAL',
        ROUND((COUNT(A) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(A) FROM AA),2) AS 'PERCENT',
        sum(count(A)) over (order by CODE asc) AS 'CUMULATIVE',
        ROUND((SUM(COUNT(A)) OVER (ORDER BY CODE ) / (SELECT COUNT(A) FROM AA) *100 ),2) AS 'CUMPERCENT'
    from AA, BB
    where AA.A= BB.code
    group by AA.A
)
    select *
from totalcount
    UNION ALL 
SELECT '0' CODE, 'TOTAL' SEX, SUM(TOTAL), SUM(PERCENT), '0' CUMULATIVE, '0.00' CUMPERCENT
    from totalcount
    ORDER BY CODE;
```

The output was this

```
CODE | SEX    | TOTAL  | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL    5        100.00    0            0.00
1      MALE     3        60.00     3            60.00
2      FEMALE   2        40.00     5            100.00
```

I used `UNION` since I want the total of these items. In this case, I inserted `0` in `TOTAL` of `SEX` column to put it in the first row. Is there another way aside from using `UNION` and inserting code `0`?

As you can see from my table BB, there are only code 1 and 2 for male and female, respectively. I want to show that the value not in this table should be in `NOT VALID`.

```
CODE | SEX       | TOTAL  | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL       6        100.00    0            0.00
1      MALE        3        50.00     3            50.00
2      FEMALE      2        33.33     5            83.33
3      NOT VALID   1        16.67     6            100.00
```

Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: please create a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) with the table and data. so we can help you

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYQJPV1X1XPbLp72LqA5CZ/0

Comment: You have no PK on your first table. Fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very tricky reporting question.  One approach uses `GROUP BY ROLLUP` to generate the total row, along with judicious use of `COALESCE` to fill in the missing values per your requirements.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.A, 0) AS CODE,
    CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(t2.DESCRIPTION, 'NOT VALID') ELSE 'TOTAL' END AS SEX,
    t1.TOTAL,
    ROUND(100.0 * t1.TOTAL / SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (), 2) AS PERCENT,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY t1.A) AS CUMULATIVE,
    ROUND(100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY t1.A) /
                  SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (), 2) AS CUMPERCENT
FROM
(
    SELECT
        A,
        COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
    FROM AA
    GROUP BY A WITH ROLLUP
) t1
LEFT JOIN BB t2
    ON t2.CODE = t1.A
ORDER BY
    CODE;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you so much. One last final question, Can I exclude the column for the 'CODE' but it will still show the same sorting for column 'SEX'?

Comment: [Yes, you can](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fae1fd0636faa526526bbf9b78fe8c6c).

Comment: I have updated the database. I just add data with a NULL value. I just want to add another row for that NULL value. Here's the updated database

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYQJPV1X1XPbLp72LqA5CZ/1

Comment: @CarloKarganilla I won't edit my answer, which already has answered your original question.  If you have follow-ups, then please ask another question.  Stack Overflow's format is not one of an ongoing question and answer session.